# itext7 barcode39 remove stop and start characters *

Tags: itext7

I'm adding a barcode to a PDF. All is well except when displayed the barcode has an "*" in the start and stop positions of the numbers below the barcode as well as  the "*"

I set the value as such

```
 Dim BCODE As iText.Barcodes.Barcode39 = New iText.Barcodes.Barcode39(Pdf)
    BCODE.SetCode("3ONWGE7C")
    Dim Barcodeimg = New Image(BCODE.CreateFormXObject(Pdf)).SetWidth(350).SetHeight(100)
```

and it displays the barcode but below it is *3ONWGE7C* . My questions is: How do I get rid of the "*"  asterisks. Can't seem to find a way. Been searching for a while now.  Thanks in advance

[image: Barcode 39]

Answer (score 0):

answer was given as a comment.  but the cure was:

barcode.setStartStopText(False)

Thanks All :)